# Using Express how to set up static folder plus views folder for dynamic content

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

These lines of code tell `express` to select `ejs` as the views engine and to render `index.ejs` as the home page when clients visit the root directory.

```
const ejs = require('ejs');

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index');
});
```

However if the site also has a static directory these instructions are disregarded.

For example this line sets up public as the default static directory for html, css, js and image files.

`app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));`

With this initialized express automatically serves the index.html file sitting in the /public directory instead of rendering index.ejs.

**Question:** How do I keep a static directory to store most of my files and also use dynamic views to render the website's home page and other pages?  They seem to interfere with each other.

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: @Vasan your post is rather an answer, than a comment.

Comment: @mbrandau Yes true. I've removed it and added an answer now. I just thought maybe OP might have tried it already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`express.static` is nothing but yet another middleware in the chain. I believe you have added it (with `app.use`) before your custom middleware. If you reorder it like so:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index');
});
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

The request to `/` will first hit your middleware and since you're finishing your response there, will not proceed to the middleware added by static.

Comment: You are 100% correct.  By reordering my code it fixed it on the spot.  Perfect!